# Upgrade PHP and keep extensions and config changes

Tags: ubuntu, php, debian, upgrade

I would like to install PHP 8.2 but keep all the packages and config changes from 8.1

In a perfect world I would run one script an this would work again for 8.3 next year.

Steps:

- Get all packages/extensions from PHP 8.1
- Change version to 8.2
- Install packages
- Copy config from `/etc/php/8.1/{apache2,cli,fpm}/conf.d/*`
- Get a diff with changes in `php.ini` files, maybe also `fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

I already got the first step:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep -i "php8.1"
```

I think the step with `php.ini` is hard. It would be better to have the `php.ini` unchanged. Instead create a `mods-available/custom.ini` and activate it with `sudo phpenmod custom`.

But I think there must be a tool/script for this already...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a debian based distro I would suggest you install all php related packages without specifying the version. For example, `php-mysql` instead of `php8.1-mysql`. This will fallback to the currently supported php version and will automatically be upgraded when this gets bumped (for example from 8.0 to 8.1).

Yes, all specific configuration for any given service/program should be kept inside the corresponding `conf.d` folder. This way you won't get any "changed file" prompts when upgrading packages and the configurations will (usually) be integrated automatically in the new version.